# Dispose Class. Do I need it?

Tags: c#

I have the following Mail classes:

```
public class Mail {
  public List<MailFile> Files { get; set; }
  public String Text { get; set; }
  // Other properties
}

public class MailFile {
  public Byte[] Data { get; set; }
  public String Mime { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
} // MailFile
```

The Mail contains a list of files where each MailFile contains a property Data which contains the File binary data. Then I send the email using Mailer.

```
public class Mailer : IMailer {

  private SmtpClient _client;

  public Mailer() {
    _client = new SmtpClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
  } // Mailer

  public void Send(Mail mail) {

    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage()) {
      message.Text = mail.Text);
      // Define other fields
      foreach (MailFile file in mail.Files)
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(x.Data), x.Name, x.Mime)));

      _client.Send(message);

    };

  } // Send

  public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
  } // Dispose

  protected virtual void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
      if (_client != null)
        _client.Dispose();
    }
  } // Dispose

} // Mailer
```

I am wrapping the MailMessage in `using`

- But do I need, in this case, to dispose the Mail Files?
- Isn't my Mail and Mail files managed and disposed by GC?
- Maybe I should make Mail disposable and dispose its MailFiles?
- If yes, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: If you need a call of `Dispose` earlier than the GC gets to it, you need a `Dispose()`; if you do not care when you get a call (or even if you get a call), then you don't need `Dispose()`.

Comment: Since you have wrapped them in a `using` statement, I don't think you need `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `IDisposable` when you use `using` keyword. Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The using statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that
>   use resources should release them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's
>   resources.

To answer your specific questions we need to see some more code.

If your `MailMessage` class contains any unmanaged resource, or streams, you definitely must release resources implementing `IDisposable` and calling `Dispose()` method from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be wrapping them in a using statement, the class needs to implement IDisposable. It won't even compile if you don't do so.

You probably only really need to free up memory if it's not managed, but setting the internal managed references to null should cover what you need.

To answer your particular questions:

- But do I need, in this case, to dispose the Mail Files?

I don't think you need to, but it wouldn't hurt, and would make it clear to the GC that there was one less reference to the objects. If you had something like:

```
String name;
using(MailFile mf = ...) {
    name = mf.Name;
}

// do something with name
```

You're still holding a reference to the actual string, so it won't get GC'd. mf should, but there's no guarantee as to when.

- Isn't my Mail and Mail files managed and disposed by GC?

Yes, but they won't be as long as a reference to the object is held somewhere. Setting it to null with nothing else referring to the actual object in memory means the GC will clean it up eventually, but with no guarantee when it will happen.

- Maybe I should make Mail disposable and dispose its MailFiles?

Not required, but a good idea, generally. Just have it implement IDisposable and set the fields to null when disposing.

- If yes, what is the best way to do it?

See previous point.